# Why does »Duden« give English translations for some words rather than explain their meaning in German?

Tags: dictionary, duden

In *the Duden*, there is no article in German dedicated to the noun *die Unwilligkeit*. Instead, only [the English translation](http://www.duden.de/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/Unwilligkeit) of the noun is provided. What's so special about *die Unwilligkeit* that *the Duden* doesn't bother explaining the meaning of the word in German? For a noun *die Käuflichkeit*, for instance, there is an [article](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaeuflichkeit) in *the Duden*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning or using the German language, but about editorial decisions of a publisher. Any speculation *why* they draw the line at any point of nominalization / negation ot other derrived form of a word in a family is opinion-based at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Duden online dictionary has an entry for [unwillig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unwillig), I assume that they did not find it necessary to also add an entry for this nominalisation.

Comment: That's reasonable. But there are separate articles in the Duden for both käuflich and die Käuflichkeit.

Comment: @EugeneStr. I'm afraid you'll have to ask the editors then